# Groups acting on trees

Tags: gr.group-theory, trees

Assume that $X$ is a tree such that every vertex has  infinite degree, and a discrete group $G$ acts on this tree  properly (with finite stabilizers)  and transitively.

Is it true that $G$ contains a non-abelian free subgroup?

Comment: Properly implies finite stabilizers

Answer (score 16):

Yes.

You're assuming more than what's necessary.

For an isometric group action on a Gromov-hyperbolic space, you have 5 possibilities (Gromov's classification):

- (a) bounded orbits
- (b) horocyclic (fixes a unique point at infinity, no loxodromic element; preserves "horospheres")
- (c) axial (preserves an axis, on which some element acts loxodromically)
- (d) focal (fixes a unique point at infinity, existence of a loxodromic element)
- (e) general type (= other): implies the existence of a non-abelian free subgroup acting metrically properly.

(a), (b), (c) are clearly ruled out in your setting (transitivity, and valency; valency $\ge 3$ would be enough). (d) is ruled out because discrete groups have no metrically proper focal action at all. So (e) holds.

The case of actions on trees is a useful motivating baby case illustrating the above "classification"; all cases can actually occur.

Comment: Thank you! And if I assume that stabilizers are amenable, will it be the same?

Comment: @MariaGerasimova you have to discard the focal case. Writing, for instance, the solvable group $\mathbf{Z}\wr\mathbf{Z}$ as an ascending HNN extension (w.r.t. an endomorphism with image of finite index), you make it act vertex-transitively on a tree with infinite valency (with abelian stabilizers). So you need to explicitly exclude the case of a fixed point at infinity.

Answer (score 4):

The geometry of simplicial trees can be extended in two directions: Gromov-hyperbolic spaces and CAT(0) cube complexes. Yves' answer is based on the first point of view. About cube complexes, we have the following statement (essentially due to Caprace and Sageev):

> **Theorem:** Let $G$ be a group acting on a finite-dimensional CAT(0) cube complex $X$. Either $G$ contains a non-abelian free subgroup or it contains a finite-index subgroup which decomposes as a short exact sequence
>   $$1 \to L \to G \to \mathbb{Z}^n \to 1$$
>   where $n \leq \dim(X)$ and where $L$ is *locally $X$-elliptic* (ie., any finitely generated subgroup of $L$ has a bounded orbit in $X$).

As a consequence, if a Tits' alternative is known for cube-stabilisers, then it is possible to deduce a Tits' alternative in the entire group. In the particular case of trees, we have:

> **Corollary:** Let $G$ be a group acting on a tree $T$. Either $G$ contains a non-abelian free subgroup or it contains a finite-index* subgroup which decomposes as a short exact sequence 
>   $$1 \to L \to G \to Z \to 1$$
>   where $L$ is locally $T$-elliptic and where $Z$ is trivial or infinite cyclic.

Of course, a direct argument can be given here.

*Sketch of proof of the corollary.* We distinguish two cases.

First, assume that $G$ has a finite orbit in $\partial T$. So it contains a finite-index subgroup $H$ which fixes a point $\xi \in \partial T$. Fix a basepoint $x \in T$. Notice that, for every $g \in H$, the intersection $g [x,\xi) \cap [x,\xi)$ contains an infinite geodesic ray (as $g$ fixes $\xi$). Consequently, $g$ defines a translation of length $\tau(g)$ on a subray of $[x,\xi)$. (Here $\tau(g)$ is positive if the translation is directed to $\xi$ and negative otherwise.) The key observation is that
$$\tau : H \to \mathbb{Z}$$
defines a homomorphism whose kernel contains only elliptic elements (as each such element fixes pointwise a subray of $[x,\xi)$). Thus, we get the desired short exact sequence.

Next, assume that $G$ has infinite orbits in $\partial T$. Play ping-pong to construct a non-abelian free subgroup. $\square$

*As noticed by Yves Cornulier in the comments, the subgroup can be always taken with index at most two.

Comment: You seem to assume (metric) properness at some point. Both the theorem and its corollary are false otherwise. Anyway I guess that the Caprace-Sageev theory is powerful enough to encompass non-proper actions.

Comment: I am not assuming anything about the action. Why do you think the statements shoudn't be correct?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's confusing (at least to me) that "locally elliptic", which I usually know as an intrinsic property of the group, is used here as a property of the action, especially since the conclusion is a mixture of intrinsic properties of $G$ (the homomorphism onto an abelian group is not related to the action, as stated here) and extrinsic (being locally elliptic).

Comment: Still there's a minor error in the corollary: it can happen that $G$ is already acting locally elliptically (horocyclic case). Side remark: in the corollary, no need to pass to a finite index subgroup, except precisely in the case $G$ preserves an axis, where one might have to pass to a subgroup of index 2.

Comment: I replaced "elliptic" with "$X$-elliptic" to avoid confusion. I also corrected the mistake in the corollary, thank you.

Comment: Do you know if the theorem has a more geometric version of the kind: if a group $G$ acting on a finite-dimensional CCC $X$ has no $F_2$ subgroup acting properly on $X$, then there is a $G$-equivariant map $f:X\to E$ to a Euclidean CCC (a finite product of copies of $\mathbf{Z}$), such that the kernel of the $G$-action on $E$ is $X$-elliptic? (Since $\mathrm{Aut}(E)$ is f.g. virtually abelian, this implies the theorem.)

Comment: I would say no, but I have to think about it. Is $f$ supposed to preserve some structure? Does it send a cube to a cube (of possibly different dimension)? A remark: it is not reasonable to ask the kernel of the $G$-action on $E$ to be $X$-elliptic; locally $X$-elliptic should be better.

Comment: But I know that, if $G$ does not contain $\mathbb{F}_2$, then there exists a $G$-invariant collection of hyperplanes $\mathcal{J}$ such that the cubulation $Y$ of the wallspace $(X, \mathcal{J})$ isometrically embeds into a Euclidean cube complex. So you have a $G$-equivariant map $X \to Y$, but $Y$ is not necessarily Euclidean. I guess its isometry group should be (locally finite)-by-(free abelian). Also, the kernel of the action on $Y$ is not necessarily $X$-elliptic, but is (locally $X$-elliptic)-by-(free abelian).

Comment: (by $X$-elliptic I meant locally $X$-elliptic)

Comment: In the case of a tree and an action not of general type, either the action is already locally $T$-elliptic, or there is an invariant axis, or an equivariant Busemann function: in the latter two cases we obtain a "factor action" $E\simeq\mathbf{Z}$ as in my previous comment. I'm expecting a substitute for this, but maybe this is too optimistic.